# Web scraping with R

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

```
<div data-projects-path="/pt/projects" id="explore_results">
  <div class="results">
    <div class="project-box" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
      <meta content="2014-08-30" itemprop="dateCreated">
      <div class="image">
        <a href="/pt/ospassosdabia" target="" title="Os passos da Bia">
          <img alt="Project thumb bia" height="172" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/7229/project_thumb_Bia.png" width="220">
        </a>
    <div class="project-box" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
      <meta content="2014-09-19" itemprop="dateCreated">
      <div class="image">
        <a href="/pt/livrepartida" target="" title="Livre Partida">
          <img alt="Project thumb logo colorido" height="172" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/7613/project_thumb_logo_colorido.jpg" width="220">
        </a>
```

This is an example HTML code that I want to scrape with R. I only need all `/pt/....` as `/pt/livrepartida` and `/pt/ospassosdabia`.

When I scroll down the web page more similar code arises and more terms like that ("pt/....")  appear.

I want to get all these "pt/...." diectly from web site. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you post the example with multiple `pt/..` terms?  It would help in testing.

Comment: look again my question, please. `/pt/...` are in the same html code like above. but this information `/pt/ ..` has a deadline to get the html code and new `/pt/....` are put every day and i want to get them

Comment: When I used the code, I get `unname(xpathSApply(doc1, "//a/@href"))#[1] "/pt/ospassosdabia" "/pt/livrepartida"`

Comment: you are right. But i want to get all those `/pt/...` directly from web site.

Comment: Does it mean that if I replicate the above lines n times, I will only get two entries instead of 2*n entries?  I tried by replicating twice and got `unname(xpathSApply(doc1, "//a/@href"))
[1] "/pt/ospassosdabia" "/pt/livrepartida"  "/pt/ospassosdabia"
[4] "/pt/livrepartida"`

Comment: you are right.but i want to know how to get doc1 (with every `/pt/..`) directly from the website using a R code

Comment: If there is a `url`, then try `doc1 <- htmlParse(url,encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: i tried it but it did not work. the value of `doc1` did not return values with that parte of html code (with all `/pt/..`). I don't know why it happens.

Comment: If the url can be shared, I can look at it.

Comment: here is http://www.catarse.me/pt/explore#in_funding

Answer (score 3):

You should give a better formatted html than this truncated one. Fortunately  , `htmlParse` can parse such corrupted format.

```
library(XML)

dd <- htmlParse(your_text,asText=TRUE)
```

Then you get href attribute :

```
xpathSApply(dd,'//a',xmlGetAttr,'href')
[1] "/pt/ospassosdabia"
```

Comment: it worked too. but there are others similar html codes that i want those information which is in the same node. when I scroll down the web page more that information that i want with similar codes appear. how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(XML)
doc1 <- htmlParse(lines)
unname(xpathSApply(doc1, "//a/@href"))
#[1] "/pt/ospassosdabia"


lines <- readLines(textConnection('<div data-projects-path="/pt/projects"    id="explore_results">
 <div class="results">
 <div class="project-box" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
 <meta content="2014-08-30" itemprop="dateCreated">
 <div class="image">
 <a href="/pt/ospassosdabia" target="" title="Os passos da Bia">
<img alt="Project thumb bia" height="172" 
  src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/7229/project_thumb_Bia.png"
  width="220">
  </a>'))
```

Comment: it worked. but there are others similar html codes that i want those information which is in the same node. how can i do that?

Comment: in the page [link](http://www.catarse.me/pt/explore#in_funding) there a lot of projects and the page url for each project has the same structure like [link](http://www.catarse.me/pt/musicasderadio)

Comment: in the page http://www.catarse.me/pt/explore#in_funding there a lot of projects and the page url for each project has the same structure like this http://www.catarse.me/pt/musicasderadio. I want only `/pt/..` that is related to this, in this example is `pt/musicasderadio`. So with your code i can't obtain that `/pt/..`.for example you can not get with your code `/pt/ospassosdabia` or `/pt/livrepartida`.

Comment: @Gabriel I couldn't find `ospassosdabia` in the new link.

Comment: yeah. with your update R code you couldn't obtain `ospassosdabia` neither `musicasderadio` neither the others that i want.